# MyFaces CoDI - Conversations/WindowContext

Tags: java, myfaces, seam2, conversation-scope, codi

Is there any possibility to switch between conversations or their contexts in MyFaces CoDI.
My concrete use case for this is that I want to implement a kind history of CustomerBeans including a CustomerEntity. If one of the entry is selected the appropriate conversation/context should be loaded.

My current implementation of this is realized with JBoss Seam 2 and there is a possibility to switch conversations.

Manager.instance().switchConversation(selectedConversation.getId());

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seam2 conversations are more like a Window-Scope. With CODI you have a (way better) Window-Scope and so you can use EditableWindowContextManager#activateWindowContext([new id]). However, I would never do something like that.